# Does Hyperledger Fabric supports encrypted transaction?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/ibjlk80wQN4?rel=0) (part of IBM course on Hyperledger Fabric) describes that it is possible to encrypt chaincode at deployment so that only a subset of members is able to decrypt it and run it. However, Fabric documentation (v0.6 and v1.0) does not provide any detail on that. Is it a feature not yet implemented that the community wish to build in the future?

It is not very clear to me how this could work. Any peer receiving a transaction from the Ordering Service that it can't decrypt would be unable to run it and update its world state, so what else can it do but just skip it ? It also can't even mark the transaction as valid or invalid.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to encrypt data **on-chain** such that chaincode is still able to see the data and apply logic on it (as opposed to an off-chain encryption where the data being garbage is not usable on chain).
The idea is to pass the encryption key as part of a transient input parameter (which is not transmitted to ordering service and other channel node). So only the endorsers and any node that get to know the key can decrypt the data. 
In v1.1 to be released on Q1 2018, Fabric will support an encryption layer API to the access state (see FAB 830).
There are 2 drawbacks of having encrypted data on chain:

- Key maintenance and sharing is overhead
- Risk of keys leakage + encryption breaking in the future

For privacy, rather than encryption, it might be better to chose a data segregation approach. That is what FAB 1151, also part of v1.1 (Experimental!) proposes:

- Each private data belongs to a collection defining the organizations which can access it
- The hash of the private state is included in the public state
- Endorser keep the private state calculated during the transaction simulation into a transient storage area and apply it at commit phase
- Other allowed nodes can request the private state via gossip

Answer (score 3):

In Fabric v1.0 there is a concept of channels to privately share data with a subset of network members.  Only members of the channel will store and have access to the data.

If you would like to encrypt the data regardless, the application may encrypt the data prior to submitting the data to the blockchain.